# Does RaspAP lock the file system?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, access-point, hostapd, mqtt

Quick question to help stop me from losing my mind.

Does the standard install of RaspAP lock the file system to stop you from installing other services?

Step 1. RaspAP installed and working fine.
[image]

Step 2. "netstat -a" and "ls" of /etc showing no Mosquitto install.
[image]
[image]

Step 3. Run "sudo apt install mosquitto mosquitto-clients" - All fine.

Step 4. "netstat -a" (Now listening on port 1883)and "ls" of /etc showing Mosquitto installed.
[image]
[image]

Step 5. Run "sudo systemctl enable mosquitto" - All fine.

Step 6. Run "sudo systemctl status mosquitto".
[image]

Step 7. Connect to mosquitto broker via MQTT Explorer - All fine.

Step 8. Publish to topic - All fine.

Step 9. Reboot Raspberry Pi and Log back in.

Step 11. All gone, no services, no folders, nada, zip, zilch!
[image]
[image]

All advice/help greatly received.

Papasean

Comment: Hello and welcome – Please avoid adding the picture of commands' output, ETC!

Comment: Sounds like maybe it is running from RAM.  Can you identify the device the root filesystem is mounted on?  Possibly by command `stat --format='device=%D' /`  (I get b302, corresponding to 179,2  or /dev/mmcblk0p2 )

Answer (score 2):

Developer of RaspAP here. The project does not lock the file system or interfere with other services. I installed mosquitto after RaspAP, enabled the service and rebooted. Confirmed it's active and listening on port 1883:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':1883'
tcp6       0      0 :::1883          LISTEN      405/mosquitto
```

Check the output of `mount -l` and look for any partitions with a read-only (ro) bit. Is your SD card full? Check with `df -h`. You could also try `sync` to flush the filesystem buffers to persistent storage, although the kernel does this during shutdown/reboot. It's also possible you have a faulty SD card.